# Error while storing the filtered records in to the same file name

Tags: linux, shell

I want to read some records alone from  a  file and store the results in a new file with same name

While trying the below command it gives the below error

```
 [omeganode files]$ grep -ve "^[19]" records.txt >> records.txt
 grep: input file ârecords.txtâ is also the output
 [omeganode files]$
```

I tried  below command then also same error . Please help me on correct command

```
 grep -ve "^[19]" records.txt > records.txt
```

Comment: Anything wrong with the obvious solution of writing results to a tmp file and then renaming?

Comment: Is that possible, Please help

Comment: Is what possible? What you are trying to do or my suggestion? You have not answered the question - is the obvious approach acceptable or not?

Comment: What is the correct approach to tmp files, would need the commands to do that

Comment: `grep -ve "^[19]" records.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt records.txt`

Comment: ok Understood , It helps for my requirement

Comment: probably not imporant in this particular case but note that `mv` will break any hard links to the file (eg. `echo 1 >a; ln a b; ls -i a b; cat a b; echo 2 >t; mv t b; ls -i a b; cat a b`); also symlinks are broken (eg. `echo 1 >a; ln -s a b; ls -l a b; cat a b; echo 2 >t; mv t b; ls -l a b; cat a b`)